# Passing pointer of unsigned int to pointer of long int

Tags: c++, c, pointers, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

I have a sample code which is working properly in 32 bit system, but when I cross compile it for 64-bit system and try to run on 64 bit Machine, it behaves differently.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

```
#include <usr/include/time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

void func(time_t * inputArg)
{
   printf("%ld\n",*inputArg);
}
int main()
{
   unsigned int input  = 123456;
   func((time_t *)&input);
}
```

Here "time_t" is a type defined in linux system library header file which is of type "long int".
This code is working fine with a 32-bit system but it isn't with 64-bit.

For 64-bit I have tried this:

```
#include <usr/include/time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

void func(time_t * inputArg)
{
   printf("%ld\n",*inputArg);
}
int main()
{
   unsigned int input  = 123456;
   time_t tempVar = (time_t)input
   func(&tempVar);
}
```

Which is working fine, but I have used the first method in my whole application a number of times. Any alternate solutions would be appreciated.

Comment: I think input should be size_t because time_t  on 64bit platform is 64bit number, so you lost half of the data, compiler should have given warning about this - atually why not just use time_t directly?

Comment: if it's time why don't just use `time_t`? That'll help you avoid a lot of undefined beviors there

Answer (score 2):

> can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Dereferencing an integer pointer of different size than the type of the pointed object has undefined behaviour.

If the pointed to integer is smaller than the pointers pointed type, you will read unrelated bytes as part of the dereferenced number.

Your fix works because you pass a pointer to an object of proper type, but consider that your input cannot represent all of the values that `time_t` can.

Best fix is to use the proper type initially. Use `time_t` as the input.

Comment: Casting between pointer types to signed/unsigned versions of the same integer type (as probably happens on the 32 bit system) and then accessing the object pointed to is not undefined. The cast is obviously possible and the aliasing is allowed per 3.10/10 item 4 of the standard which allows access to an object though "a type [i.e. the dereferenced alias pointer, -ps] that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a cv-qualified version of the dynamic type of the object". Making these type assumptions is just not portable which is the reson for types.h.

Comment: @PeterSchneider ah, I've tried to correct my answer in that regard now.

Answer (score 0):

Your "fixed" code has a cast that lets the compiler convert your `unsigned int` value to a `time_t`. Your original code assumes that they're identical.

On your 32-bit system they are identical, so you get lucky. On your 64-bit system you find out what happens when you invoke Undefined Behavior.

In other words, both C and C++ allow you to cast pointers to whatever you want, but it's up to you to make sure such casts are safe.

Comment: If you mean the second snipped with "fixed code", i.e. `time_t tempVar = (time_t)input`, the cast doesn't do anything. It's an explicit notation for one of the standard conversions, namely an integer promotion (assuming that time_t is an integer). It could simply be left out without any semantic or generated code differences (because time_t will be at least as large as an `int`).

Comment: AFAIK there is no guarantee that `time_t` is as large as an `int`, or even that it *is* an `int`. Although in practice it basically is. Still, the point is that there is a place where the conversion can take place. Although strictly speaking, even that conversion, explicit or not, is undefined behavior.

Comment: Looks as if time_t can be a floating point type (cf. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/sys/types.h.html). But no matter what the size or arithmetic type of size_t, conversion from any integer type to size_t are almost always  *implementation defined* (as opposed to UB). The only UB case is if the value of the `unsigned int` `input` is "outside the range of values that can be represented" in the floating point type which is probably false for most combinations of `unsigned int` vs. `some float`. Btw, UB may occur in printf... safest to convert to double for print.

Comment: Adam ya... I was lucky..!! Thank you.

Comment: @PeterSchneider the question is about `time_t`, not `size_t`. Although your point is valid with both.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for response.
Actually I found my mistake when I printed sizeof 'long int' in 32bit machine and 64bit machine.

**32bit machine** :
sizeof(int) = 32bit & sizeof(long int) = 32 bit & sizeof(long long int) = 64 bit
**64bit machine**:
sizeof(int) = 32bit & sizeof(long int) = 64 bit & sizeof(long long int) = 64 bit

Comment: what does `long int` have to do with anything? Compare `int` and `time_t`.

Comment: time_t internaly typecasted in to "long int".

Comment: That might be true on that particular platform, but the language makes no such guarantee. Since your question boils down to platform differences, I don't get why you insist on making even more platform-dependent assumptions.