# ioctl giving error in different executions

Tags: c, pointers, casting, embedded, spi

For the next system: VAR-DART-MX8M (https://variwiki.com/index.php?title=DART-MX8M)(It is a ARM A-53 cortex based system)

Kernel version: Linux Debian Stretch version (kernel 4.14.78)

I use Eclipse to write the code and then cross compile to the specified system.

I want to use an SPI bus in my embedded system to communicate with an FPGA. I have read that casting pointers can lead to undefined behaviour: [Passing pointer of unsigned int to pointer of long int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29692455/passing-pointer-of-unsigned-int-to-pointer-of-long-int)

The problem is that I have to cast some parameters in order to meet the *spi_ioc_transfer struct* requirements:

```
int transfer16(int fd, uint16_t *tx, uint16_t *rx, uint32_t len){

int ret;
errno=0;

tr.tx_buf = (unsigned long)tx;
tr.rx_buf = (unsigned long)rx;
tr.len = len;
tr.delay_usecs = 1;
tr.speed_hz = spi_speed;
tr.bits_per_word = 16;

ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_MESSAGE(1), &tr);
     if (errno != 0){
         printf("SPI IOCTL ret(%d), error(%d) %s\n", ret, errno, 
         strerror(errno));
     }
return ret;
}
```

Where `tr` is the `struct spi_ioc_transfer` provided by spidev.h (declared as global variable).

The function transfer16 is called by the following function:

```
int send_command_readadc(int fd, int16_t *rx, uint16_t ndata_adc, uint8_t membank) {

int ret;

uint16_t tx[2];
uint16_t crc16_o, crc16_i;
uint8_t rcommand;
uint8_t ack;
uint32_t len = 2*(ndata_adc+NUMELS(tx)+2); // 2*sizeof(rx)
int i = 0;

tx[0] = (THE_READADC_COMMAND << 8) + membank;
tx[1] = crc16_uint16_false(tx,NUMELS(tx)-1);

ret = transfer16(fd, tx, rx, len);

if (ret==-1) {
    return -1;
}
```

And I call this function using the following parameters:

```
ret = send_command_readadc(fd_spi, (int16_t *)(data_adc+(ndata_adc+4)*i), ndata_adc, membank);
```

Where `data_adc` is a pointer to a allocated part of memory where I want to save the ADC readings:

```
data_adc = (int16_t *) calloc((ndata_adc+4)*M,sizeof(int16_t));
```

So, for example, if M is 3 I save the quantity of `(ndata_adc+4)` starting from the register `data_adc`. Then `(ndata_adc+4)` starting from the register `data_adc+(ndata_adc+4)` etc.

The function transfer16 sometimes doesn't work properly, as same exact executions can have different results:

[image: Same execution (./myspi.elf -a 234), second one giving bad address error]

Any tip on how to proceed with this issue?

If you need more information about the problem, ask without hesitation.

Thanks!

Comment: What is `tr`? Where is it defined and initialized? What is e.g. `tr.tx_buf`? What is the size of `unsigned long`? What is the size of `uint16_t *`? Are there uninitialized members of the `tr` structure?

Comment: I would suggest using NXP HAL for that. Also use fixed length types

Comment: tr is the name I give to the spi_ioc_transfer, which is declared as a global variable outside this function as struct spi_ioc_transfer tr;.  tx_buf, rx_buf etc. are variables within this struct, which are defined in spidev.h. Unsigned long is 32 bit long (I have also used fixed length types, this doesn't solve the issue).

Comment: Using some printf-s I have seen that unsigned long is 8 byte size and uint16_t* is also 8 byte size

Comment: *This function sometimes doesn't work properly ...* is ambiguous. What is happening?

Comment: Having the exact same execution, ioctl() sometimes gives bad address error, while sometimes just works fine

Comment: Why is it a global variable? Try to avoid global variables, especially for things that aren't shared between functions (like the `tr` structure).

Comment: Of by the way, only check `errno` if the function actually failed. Unless documented otherwise (which is rather unusual), `errno` will only be set if the function fails, and will have an *indeterminate* value otherwise. You should check `ret`, not `errno`: `if (ret == -1)`.

Comment: I used to check `ret` instead of `errno` and changed it recently. I will correct that.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude `tr` used to be a local variable but also changed it recently to see if it had some effect on the results.

Comment: Using `unsigned long` on a 64 bit CPU is to ask for problems. Is it 32 bit, is it 64 bits? Nobody knows. There's no reason why you should use any of C's "primitive data types", use stdint.h everywhere.

Comment: Even using stdint.h data types, I still have the same issue

Comment: As for the sizes, print the values of the `sizeof` operator. For example `printf("sizeof tx_buf = %zu, sizeof(unsigned long) = %zu, sizeof(uint16_t*) = %zu\n", sizeof tr.tx_buf, sizeof(unsigned long), sizeof(uint16_t*));` Also, the structures `tx_buf` and `rx_buf` members have the type `__u64`, which might be different from `unsigned long` (which is why I added the `sizeof tr.tx_buf` in my printout example).

Comment: Other than that, the most common reason for having a SPI that only works sometimes, is "clock skew". That is, you might have messed up CPOL and CPHA settings versus what the SPI slave expects. Double & triple check this, it is always a pain in the neck when working with SPI.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude using your example, it prints this: "sizeof tx_buf = 8, sizeof(unsigned long) = 8, sizeof(uint16_t*) = 8"

Comment: Okay, that at least tells us there's no size mismatch between the types. So while still not good, the casting shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: I would omit the cast "(unsigned long) tx;". Both sides of the assignment are pointers, right? So why cast to a non-pointer type? Probably it does not matter but it is ugly.

Comment: The `rx_buf` and `tx_buf` are not pointers, in spidev_test.c https://raw.githubusercontent.com/raspberrypi/linux/rpi-3.10.y/Documentation/spi/spidev_test.c , here in the `transfer` function it casts the `rx_buf` and `tx_buf`. Also if I don't cast it gives me a warning

Comment: ..then there is something suspicious... so it means we can not transfer more than 8 bytes? What if the caller want to send/receive 256 bytes? It seems to me that the original function and ioctl serve two different purposes.

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre]. Never describe a problem merely as “doesn't work properly”. Always state the observed behavior and the behavior desired instead.

Comment: In that example, there is an array of bytes, "tx[]", then the assignment ".tx_buf = (unsigned long)tx". I find it strange. The array contains 38 bytes, and tr.len is assigned "ARRAY_SIZE(tx)". I don't find the header <spidev.h>, but I see more than one strangeness.

Comment: @EricPostpischil question edited

Answer (score 0):

I have solutioned this problem this way:

Instead of using `data_adc = (int16_t *) calloc((ndata_adc+4)*M,sizeof(int16_t));` , I declared an array `int16_t data_adc_static[(ndata_adc+4)*M];` and I give the next address `int16_t *address = &data_adc_static[(ndata_adc+4)*i];` to the `send_command_readadc` command.

This way the problem that I had desappeared.

Thanks everybody for your answers